# Raise exception in function call when event is triggered

Tags: c#, vb.net, exception, events

I have a VB.NET class `Flasher` used to flash a device with some firmware via the `.Flash()` method. However, during the flashing process an error might occur, in which case an event will be triggered. I cannot figure out how to handle this event and raise an exception in the callstack of `.Flash()`.

```
Class Flasher
    Private myDevice As New FlashLib.Device

    Public Function Flash() As String
        AddHandler myDevice.ErrorEvent, AddressOf OnError
        '... Do flashing stuff here that might send our `ErrorEvent` ...'
        myDevice.flash_firmware("myfirmware.fw")
        myDevice.restart()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        return "OK"
    End Function

    Public Sub OnError(ByRef Err As ErrEventArgs)
        errMsg = String.Format(
            "Device threw an error during flashing process. Type: {0}",
            Err.error)
        Throw New System.Exception(errMsg)
    End Sub
```

The `Flasher` class depends on a C# library `FlashLib` that is the originator of the `ErrorEvent`:

```
namespace FlashLib
{
    public delegate void ErrorEventHandler(ErrEventArgs err);

    public interface Device
    {
        event ErrorEventHandler ErrorEvent;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I instantiate `Flasher` and call `.Flash()` the idea is if there's an error event, the caller of `.Flash()` will be thrown an exception, however what happens is in the middle of `.Flash()` execution jumps out of that function and into `OnError()`. Throwing an exception from here isn't caught by my `catch` clause:

```
Dim flasher As New Flasher
Try
    flasher.Flash()
Catch
    Debug.Print("There was a problem with flashing")
End Try
```

Instead the exception rises to the top and I get shown an error message box. Then execution *continues* from where it left off in the `Flash()` method and carries on. It seems that events in VB.NET behave like software interrupts: jump out of whatever you're doing into the handler, and then resume where you were before? I need the caller of `Flash()` to be able to catch an exception when an `ErrorEvent` is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than your `OnError` method throwing an exception, have it set a flag that you can test for in `Flash` and then then throw the exception if you find it set.  E.g.

```vb
Class Flasher
    Private myDevice As New FlashLib.Device
    Private errMsg As String

    Public Function Flash() As String
        AddHandler myDevice.ErrorEvent, AddressOf OnError
        '... Do flashing stuff here that might send our `ErrorEvent` ...'

        If errMsg IsNot Nothing Then
            Throw New System.Exception(errMsg)
        End If

        myDevice.flash_firmware("myfirmware.fw")
        myDevice.restart()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        return "OK"
    End Function

    Public Sub OnError(ByRef Err As ErrEventArgs)
        errMsg = String.Format(
            "Device threw an error during flashing process. Type: {0}",
            Err.error)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the problem is that the error event can be triggered at any time (imagine the cable of the device is disconnected). Is there any alternative than to do the check for `errMsg` between every single line of code (there can be hundreds)?

Comment: Not really that I can think of.  At least you could make the `If` block a one-liner and then just copy and paste.  You could conceivably create a delegate for each line of code and add them all to a list, then loop through the list and do one invocation and one error check inside the loop.  Might not really help though, as you'd have to make more changes to the code.

Comment: I think what I'm asking for is illogical. You're right, I must compromise and do the check for if an error happened at key lines in the code that would be likely to have caused an error. Thanks!